# TSQL: How to select a range based on multiple columns

Tags: t-sql

First of all, apologies if this question (my first in stackoverflow) is a duplicate and I could not find it. I am brand new so still learning the ropes.

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
C1  C2  C2  C4
-------------------
1   11  111 1111
1   11  222 1111
1   22  222 2222
1   22  444 2222
1   33  444 3333
2   22  333 2222
2   33  333 3333
2   33  333 4444

2   44  444 1111 -- start range
2   44  444 4444
3   11  111 2222
3   11  222 2222 -- end range

3   22  333 2222
3   22  444 2222
4   11  111 4444
4   11  222 1111
4   44  222 2222
4   44  333 1111
```

How do I select all rows **outside** "start range" and "end range"?

The way I am doing it is this, but I wonder whether there's a better way?

```
select * from Table1

where
    -- start range
    Col1 < 2
    or
    Col1 = 2 and Col2 < 44
    or
    Col1 = 2 and Col2 = 44 and Col3 < 444
    or
    Col1 = 2 and Col2 = 44 and Col3 = 444 and Col4 < 1111
    -- end range
    or
    Col1 > 3
    or
    Col1 = 3 and Col2 > 11
    or
    Col1 = 3 and Col2 = 11 and Col3 > 222
    or
    Col1 = 3 and Col2 = 11 and Col3 = 222 and Col4 > 2222
```

I would like to clarify that what I am after is whether there is any way to avoid all the all those "or" conditions; something like MySQL does it with:

where
    (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) < (2, 44, 444, 1111)
    or
    (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) > (3, 11, 222, 2222)

Also, a couple of additional points:

- The 4 columns are unique combinations (imagine a primary key over all
  4 columns);
- I have no control over the structure of the table, this is what I
  get;
- The number of columns is arbitrary (I need to generate the TSQL
  programmatically);
- The data I have shown are just for the sake of the    question, the
  real data are more complex.

Comment: I think maybe you need to improve your data model such that you are storing single numbers and not fragments across separate columns.  Beyond making querying difficult, your current design might make it harder to use an index.

Comment: Can use Except operator

Comment: @Paparazzi Dang beat me to it

Comment: Thank you for you comments and replies, I have edited the question as I think I didn't make clear what I am after. Apologies for that!

Answer (score 0):

I would do an except operator (as Paparazzi already mentioned)

```
Select *
from YourTable
Except
select *
from YourTable
where (C1 = 2 and C2 >= 44 and C3 >= 444 and C4 >= 1111)
  or (C1 = 3 and C2 >= 11 and C3 <= 222 and C4 <= 2222)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I see that you only check C1 and C2 which would work in this case. To clarify, all columns need to be checked as the next row after the range could be (3, 11, 333, 2222) and should be selected.

Comment: Updated, the issue to really understand should be I am hunting for the set You want to exclude for everything under the 'Except' and then using the entire set above that.  You can change whatever predicates you want for your qualifications.  I just made the predicate as short as possible for what I thought you wanted.  I updated it slightly to better serve your needs.